# Retrieve data from Chrome localStorage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an Array storing objects each with another array inside. I'm using the Chrome Storage API to store these objects (for an extension). Writing data works fine, but I can't seem to extract the data I need:

Write to storage:

```
function writeToStorage(form) {
  var formObjectsArr = [];
  var data = [];
  var formData;
  $(':input', '#' + form)
      .each(function() { data.push(this.value); })
      .promise()
      .done(function() {
        var formData = new Form(data);
        formObjectsArr.push(formData);
        chromeStorage(formObjectsArr);
      });
}

function chromeStorage(formObjectsArr) {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({list:formObjectsArr}, function() {
    console.log('Settings saved');
  });
}

function Form(data) { this.data = data; }
```

Read from storage (not sure what to do here - the current function simply returns an object which contains an array which contains the object that contains *the* array I want to access):

```
function getFromStorage() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get({list:[]}, function(test) {
    console.log(data)
  });
}
```

Comment: 1. chrome.storage is not `localStorage`,that's another API 2. there are lots of easily [googlable examples](https://www.google.com/#q=+chrome.storage.sync.get+example)........

Comment: Please add the google chrome extension tag. Also, you are not using localStorage on the chrome extensions API. You are using sync storage which stores data on Chrome's Sync servers centrally. This allows for all devices connected to a single profile to share data and sync across when changes occur.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a string, array of strings, or a object dictionary to retrieve data stored in chrome extension's local or sync storage. Since you only want to retrieve the `list` keyed data, you can just use a string for the first argument of the `sync.get` method.

```
function getFromStorage() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("list", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```